# How to solve Generating same name 'Lad;' when given a new minified name error Android

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I have an android application which is already in playstore. When I try to make a new release build of my application it gives me this error.

> Generating same name 'Lad;' when given a new minified name to 'android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Rectangle'.

I didn't change anything in `proguard-rules.pro` after my first release. Please help. I checked for duplicate values in `dictionary` files, but nothing found. What would be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This was happen as I upgrade my `graddle` from `3.1.3` to `3.5.0`. Google introduce new code shrink tool `R8`. So I have disable it for my project to work it like before.

this is what I add to my `graddle.properties` file,

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

Details about `R8`

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html